Methods to show that a singularity in a variety is not a quotient singularity
Let $X$ be a variety (irreducible, normal) over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and let $p\in X$ be a singular point. To simplify things, I'll assume that $X$ is affine and that $p$ is the unique singularity, but feel free to disregard these assumptions if you wish. I have a fairly general question:

What are some methods to show that $p$ is not a quotient singularity?

To be clear, by quotient singularity here I mean that there is an étale neighbourhood of $p$ of the form $W/F$ where $W$ is a smooth variety and $F$ is a finite group. Since we are in characteristic $0$, we can assume that $W=\mathbb{A}^n$ and $F$ acts linearly; also in this case (since I'm assuming $p$ is isolated), $F$ acts freely on $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus 0$.
I'll note that, if $X$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial (around $p$, at least), then $p$ cannot be a quotient singularity, so we may assume that $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial. For similar reasons, we may assume that $X$ is rationally smooth and that $p$ is at least log-terminal.

for example, if the local fundamental group of $X\setminus p$ is trivial.

@ChenJiang thanks for your comment. What exactly is the local fundamental group in this context? My understanding if $X$ is an analytic space over $\mathbb{C}$ is that this group is the fundamental group of $X\setminus p$ intersected with some ball around $p$.
